# Get value from input text in php without pressing Enter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hay I'm new to php and I have made php code like this :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo 'Hellow Hisoka';
?>
<form name="form" method="post">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label class:>Nama :</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="nama_tamu" id='nama_tamu' class="form-control" placeholder="Nama Lengkap">
        <?php
            $myValue = $_POST['nama_tamu'];     
        ?>
    </div> 
    <br/><br/>
    <?php
        echo $myValue;
    ?>
</form>
```

When I want to show the echo message, I need to hit `enter` on my keyboard first in order to get the value of `$_POST['nama_tamu'];`. My question is can I get the value of `nama_tamu` input without pressing `enter`, or maybe without using `POST` or `GET` and then assign it to $myvalue?

Comment: Do it with js... with keyup event in Jquery

Comment: do you have any example code for doing that Mr. Maninderpreet ..?? :)

Comment: U can use jquery for the same.. http://jsfiddle.net/Dinvi/2nbe7da6/

Comment: JQuery(SELECTOR).on('keyup',function(){ jQuery(IDORCLASSWHEREYOUPRINTMESSAGE).append(jQuery(this).val());});

Comment: Glad to help you...@Hyosoka Poipo

Comment: @Saty I don't think "javascript" and "jquery" are appropriate tags here, as the question didn't mention any use of client-side scripting. And I highly doubt the difference of client-side and server-side scripting was understood at all.

Comment: @Eiko but  solution of this question only possible with JavaScript or jquery. PHP standalone quite not enough

Comment: @Saty It's just that this question has nothing to do with javascript. Not at all. In fact, the correct answer would be "not possible" obviously. Javascript is just one of many possibilities to solve the problem. One could suggest a flash applet and tag it as "flash", but it won't make it a question about flash. Or java. Or any other client-side language including javascript. As it stands, it looks as if Hyosoka Poipo was using or looking for a javascript solution - which he clearly was not.

Comment: Mr. Eiko, my goals is to assign the value of nama_tamu to $myValue without have to hit enter.... :D
and Mr.Saty,,, yaaps.. I dont really understand the way server-side or client-side work... Weelll.. I"m new to php... :D

Thank you so much btw... :)

Comment: Aaand rightnow, I'm reading about ajax... :v
fiiiiuh....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For this purpose you should use `.keyup` function/event. Following are the snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#nama_tamu").keyup(function(){
    $("#enterdata").html($("#nama_tamu").val());
     $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
  url:  "getdata.php",
  data: "nama_tamu="+$("#nama_tamu").val(),
  success: function(res)
  {
   $("#outputdata").html(res);
  }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
    session_start();
    echo 'Hellow Hisoka';
?>
<form name="form" method="post">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label class:>Nama :</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="nama_tamu" id='nama_tamu' class="form-control" placeholder="Nama Lengkap">
        <?php
            $myValue = $_POST['nama_tamu'];     
        ?>
     <br> You press following character:<div id="enterdata"> </div>
    </div> 
    <br/><br/>
    <div id="outputdata"></div>
    <?php
        echo $myValue;
    ?>
</form>
```

Also create one file for the required output.

Now in getdata.php file

```
  echo $nama_tamu=$_POST['nama_tamu'];
```

Comment: btw... Mr. Divyesh How do I assign the nama_tamu value to $myValue ..?

Comment: U can use json for the same.

Comment: mmm... I have no idea... Would you like to show me the code Mr. Divyesh..?? :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `keyup()`.

```js
function check(id)
{
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = id;  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" onkeyup="check(this.value);">
Your value: <span id="result"> </span>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#check").keyup(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="check" >
```

Comment: onkeyup seems not work... Because It's still needed an enter key to be pressed...

Comment: check live example. @HyosokaPoipo

Comment: added both javascript and jquery code. @HyosokaPoipo

Comment: Okiee... Thanks a lot Mr. Ruchish... But That's not what I mean... :)

Comment: Okiee... Thanks a lot Mr. Ruchish... But That's not what I mean... :)

Comment: Okiee... Thanks a lot Mr. Ruchish... But That's not what I mean... :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Javascript. You can use the [Jquery events](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/) :

```
<script>
    $( "#nama_tamu" ).keyup(function() {
        alert( $this.val() );// alerting the value of the input field
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Web development is all about communication. In this case, communication between two (2) parties, over the HTTP protocol:
>
> - The Server - This party is responsible for serving pages.
> - The Client - This party requests pages from the Server, and displays them to the user. In most cases, the client is a web browser.

Each side's programming, refers to code which runs at the specific machine, the server's or the client's.

You cannot get values without submitting for the user has not entered any yet. PHP is a server side language. To get values before submit and do certain actions with them you will need javascript (a client side programming language).

The simplest method to get a value is using the `getElementById()`.

```
var something = document.getElementById('someid');

<input type="text" name="something" id="someid">
```

You can also use jQuery:

```
var something = $('#someid').val();
```

#### Conclusion

The simple answer to your question is: This is not possible.

Why not? I hear you asking. Because PHP doesn't know the values of your form before you send the form to your webserver.